# Create Objects to Return entire row

Tags: parse-platform

In Parse.com, Is it possible to receive entire row in the response after making Create Object call instead of receiving the objectId alone.

For example below command

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: qEXLVybHgoqX79zKIpjA2wIGL5suvbVyZDA9Lt4A" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: RSJfkl80UCLC24TYqaUjKqJmtoFtRojNRXTVPxMj" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"score":1337,"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

returns output response as

```
{
  "createdAt": "2011-08-20T02:06:57.931Z",
  "objectId": "Ed1nuqPvcm"
}
```

Instead of this is it possible to retrieve entire object in the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately the API does not support that (which I have missed on several occasions). You will need to re-fetch the object after it is saved.